# Submit tag-based form when hitting enter

Tags: jquery

I have a tag-based search form (just like the tag-based text boxes you see on Facebook or S/O where you enter a word and press the corresponding delimiter key on the keyboard)

On my website, you type a word in the text field, and press enter to 'confirm' or 'accept' that keyword, which enables you to enter another.

The problem with this is, that even though you may have finished entering your search query, pressing enter does not submit the form (obviously), because e.preventDefault() has been enabled so i can use enter button to accept/confirm each tag.

What I want to do is, instead of (albeit, slightly) inconveciencing my users, is to submit the form when they press enter if they have not entered any (or any new) tags.

I'll try to explain it more clearly with this image:
[image]

Would this at all be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#tags").keyup( function(e){
    if ( e.which === 13 ) {
        if ( /*value is not empty*/ ) { //add tag             
        } else {
            $("#formID").submit();
        }
    }
});
```

i think that this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to check the state. For instance, when they are in the process of selecting tags, you could add the class `.tagging` to the element. When they press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you can check to see if the `.tagging` class is on the element. If it is, finalize the tag-selection and remove the class. If the class is not on the element, that means they're not tagging, and therefore you can go ahead and submit the changes.

```
$("#tags").on("keypress", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ( e.which === 13 ) {
        if ( $(this).is(".tagging") ) {
            /* Add tag, remove class */
        } else {
            /* Submit data */
        }
    }
});
```